Nginx command failed because of permission
I am trying to test the configuration of nginx on my machine and I read somewhere it's bug and I have to do the following which I did:
  sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
  printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" | \
  sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  sudo systemctl restart nginx

Yet I get the same error still:
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

How do I fix this please?
Here is my system information:
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0 Desktop: MATE 1.26.0
    info: mate-panel wm: marco 1.26.0 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: HP product: HP EliteDesk 800 G2 SFF v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
    Chassis: type: 4 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8054 v: KBC Version 05.39 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: HP
    v: N01 Ver. 02.60 date: 12/15/2022
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-6500 bits: 64 type: MCP smt: <unsupported> arch: Skylake-S
    rev: 3 cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3419 high: 3483 min/max: 800/3600 cores: 1: 3476 2: 3483 3: 3373 4: 3345
    bogomips: 25599
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx

